# Detect two touches separately and handle them at the same time

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I have two `SKSpriteKitNodes`, one in the left and one in the right. Then I detect where is the location of the touch and make the action according to its location (the left side shoots, and the right side speeds up). But the thing is, if the left is being touched, how can I handle the right-side touch at the same time?

The code I have so far:

```
let left = SKSpriteNode()
let right = SKSpriteNode()

override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    left.size = CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height)
    right.size = CGSize(width: frame.width / 2, height: frame.height)

    left.position = CGPoint(x: frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 2)
    right.position = CGPoint(x: 3 * frame.width / 4, y: frame.height / 2)

}



override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches{
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)

        if right.containsPoint(location){
            //HANDLE THE SPEED

            if speed == 0{
                speed = 5
            }
            shouldBreak = false
        }
        if left.containsPoint(location){
            //HANDLE THE SHOOTING
            shoot.position = CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.height * 0.2)
            isShooting = true
        }


    }
```

Comment: You can use one flag per node to know if each node is touched. You can set to true in the touchesbegan and false in the touchesended and also when the left node is touched you check the right flag and viceversa to know if you have to do any action you need to do.

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate_Protocol/#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIGestureRecognizerDelegate/gestureRecognizer:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWithGestureRecognizer:

Comment: Look at 'Controlling Simultaneous Gesture Recognition'

Comment: @CrApHeR I didn't really understand what you said, can you explain how to do it?

Comment: @Aggressor do you think that using UIGestureRecognizer is really necessary when using SpriteKit? I mean, I don't know, but there must be a way to do it

Comment: Don't be afraid to get your hands dirty, that's how you learn!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343926/multi-touch-gesture-in-sprite-kit

Comment: @GabrielBitencourt It is too difficult to explain in the comments section because the space to write is not enough, but you can see the 0x141E comment, it can help you with the problem.