# Swift SpriteKit: Recognize multiple taps

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, sprite-kit, multi-touch

I have a game and at the moment there is an AI player and human but I want to make it multiplayer.  The game is designed where when you press the top left/right the sprite on top would move left/right and if you press the lower left/right the lower sprite would move towards the left/right.  Imagine the iPhone to always be in portrait mode.

The issue is that I am using `touchesBegan` and I can't figure out how to make that work with possible multiple taps coming in at the same time

Comment: all your taps are generated from the same UIView?

Comment: If the default is yes, then yes.  Im not using the story board.  I built it programmatically with SKScene

Comment: This may be what you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27343926/multi-touch-gesture-in-sprite-kit

Comment: thanks i didn't try it yet but i dont see any reason why that wouldn't work