# Split Screen into Two View Controllers SpritKit + Swift

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am making a simple Pong game using SpriteKit + Swift. I am trying to move the two paddles even if a finger is already touching the display. I got a suggestion to split the screen into two View Controller. Would this help? If so, how would this be done?
[Link to previous question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33194394/move-two-paddles-at-same-time-in-spritekit-swift)

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
    let touchLocation = touch?.locationInNode(self)
    let body: SKPhysicsBody? = self.physicsWorld.bodyAtPoint(touchLocation!)

    if body?.node!.name == PaddleCategoryName {
        print("Paddle Touched!")
        fingerIsOnPaddle = true
    }

    if body?.node!.name == PaddleCategoryName2 {
        print("Paddle2 Touched!")
        fingerIsOnPaddle2 = true
    }


}

override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    if fingerIsOnPaddle {
        let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
        let touchLocation = touch?.locationInNode(self)
        let previousTouchLocation = touch?.previousLocationInNode(self)

        let paddle = self.childNodeWithName(PaddleCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode

        var newYPosition = paddle.position.y + (touchLocation!.y - previousTouchLocation!.y)

        newYPosition = max(paddle.size.height / 2, newYPosition)
        newYPosition = min(self.size.height - paddle.size.height / 2, newYPosition)

        paddle.position = CGPointMake(paddle.position.x, newYPosition)

    }

    if fingerIsOnPaddle2 {
        let touch = touches.first as UITouch?
        let touchLocation = touch?.locationInNode(self)
        let previousTouchLocation = touch?.previousLocationInNode(self)

        let paddle2 = self.childNodeWithName(PaddleCategoryName2) as! SKSpriteNode

        var newYPosition = paddle2.position.y + (touchLocation!.y - previousTouchLocation!.y)

        newYPosition = max(paddle2.size.height / 2, newYPosition)
        newYPosition = min(self.size.height - paddle2.size.height / 2, newYPosition)

        paddle2.position = CGPointMake(paddle2.position.x, newYPosition)
    }
}

override func touchesEnded(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    fingerIsOnPaddle = false
    fingerIsOnPaddle2 = false
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure that is really what you want to do.  You might be better getting the location of the touch, so you can just use that location to see if it on one side of the iDevice or the other.  Same would go for `touchesMoved`, just see where the location of the touch is, and move the paddle on that side.

Comment: I did try that, but it still did not work.

Comment: What errors did you run into?  Would you be able to show some of that code?

Comment: Basically, I made two nodes that were tilted LeftSide and RightSide. If LeftSide was pressed then, it would find if I pressed on Paddle1 which is on the left side and vice versa. When I ran the changes, I was still running into the same problem.

Comment: I added the code in the question.

Comment: You are only using the first touch (by `touches.first`). That may be why you don't get the touches all the time.  Also, would it just be better not to detect a touch _on_ the paddle, but set the position of the paddle to where the touch is?  I would do something like (saying that this game is horizontal): `if touchLocation.x > self.view.frame.size.width { set paddle1 position.y to touchLocation.y } else { set paddle2 position.y to touchLocation.y }` rather than detecting if it on one side of the screen, and then detecting if you are touching the paddle. Are you using `touchesMoved` for moving?

Comment: I am using touchesMoved for moving.

Comment: I added the code I have for touchesBegan, touchesMoved, and touchesEnded for you to look at.

Comment: Thank you, that explains a lot.  I'll write up an answer later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The primary problem with the code you have provided is that you are *only* using the first touch, which is not good when you have two people moving the paddles around.  I would in fact not use `touchesBegan` or `touchesEnded`.  I'm going to assume that the game field will have `x` along the horizontal, so 512 (the default scene width divided by 2) will be the middle line, with the paddles positioned at `x = 0` and `x = 1024`.

The code below is in `touchesMoved`, and handles each touch that moved.  If the touch location is on one side of the screen, it gets the paddle for that side and moves it.  You may wish to put this code in the `touchesBegan` method as well, so that the user can touch where they want the paddle to go.  You could go back to your paddle detection method (I didn't see anything wrong with it aside from not using every touch), but I would recommend using `paddle.containsPoint` to test if the touch is inside.

```
override func touchesMoved(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    for touch: UITouch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        if location.x < 512 {
            let paddle = self.childNodeWithName(PaddleCategoryName) as! SKSpriteNode
            paddle.position.y = location.y
        } else {
            let paddle2 = self.childNodeWithName(PaddleCategoryName2) as! SKSpriteNode
            paddle2.position.y = location.y
        }
    }
}
```

I am currently downloading Xcode 7 to get Swift 2, and I will edit this with proper syntax.  But for now, with a few changes (like to the method call), it should work.